# Convert Tailwind classes to css inline style

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, react-native-stylesheet

In these days i'm struggling with the conversion from a react app to a react-native app;
in this react app i used tailwind to stylize components thus i need to convert tailwind classes to inline css so that i can convert it to react native stylesheet using a tool online.
Is there a way or tool to get css from Tailwind code?

i.e.
(Tailwind code) "`w-full h-full bg-black`" after conversion should be (vanilla css) { `width : 100%; height : 100%; background-color : black;`}

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a question. What are you asking?

Comment: I mean, is there a tool for this?

Comment: Have you perhaps tried a package like this, which allows tailwind in RN: https://github.com/vadimdemedes/tailwind-rn ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to this problem is : `Tailwind-rn` (as Mando replied)

Thanks to this packet it is possible to copy the entire tailwind code from react project and paste it as param of the function `tailwind()` which returns a react-native stylesheet object.

Here's the docs :

https://github.com/vadimdemedes/tailwind-rn

Answer (score 0):

This is a very specific scenario that has a very specific solution.

In a more general case (that you really want to extract the vanilla css of any HTML file using tailwindcss), there is a quick tutorial for that.

[Extracting TailwindCSS from HTML](https://devdojo.com/tnylea/extracting-tailwindcss-from-html)